# double audio output

Tags: sound, pulseaudio

I'm trying to have the audio output of my PC on both headset and HDMI at the same time, but I can't find a working solution.

Does anyone have a clue for me ?

The goal is to have the sound on a screen if it's up and on the headset all the time.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Install Paprefs

The easiest way to enable audio playback from multiple sources is to use a simple graphical utility called `paprefs` It’s short for PulseAudio Preferences.

It’s available through the Ubuntu repositories, so just install it with Apt.

```
sudo apt install paprefs
```

When the install finishes, you can just launch the program.

Even though the utility is graphical, it’s still probably easier to launch it by typing paprefs in the command line as a regular user.

The window that opens has a few tabs with settings that you can tweak. The tab that you're looking for is the last one, "Simultaneous Output."

Next, open up the regular sound preferences. It's in different places on different distributions. On Ubuntu it'll be under the GNOME system settings.

Once you have your sound preferences open, select the "Output" tab. Select the "Simultaneous output" radio button. It’s now your default output.

[Reference](https://www.maketecheasier.com/play-sound-through-multiple-devices-linux/)

Comment: I already did.
But the second virtual output is cloned on the first one so when I select HDMI output for the hardware output, the virtual one is automatically redirected on HDMI too.
It's on my desktop at work and I don't have admin privileges on it, maybe it's related ?

Comment: paprefs is installed, this is not the issue. But maybe it's mandatory to be root to run it with full capabilities

Comment: No, root not needed to enable it. Did you follow guide carefully?

Comment: On paprefs no issue. I ticked the box to add the virtual output.
Next on pavucontrol, I can see the virtual output on output devices tab, but if I select HDMI on Configuration tab both Internal and virtual device are shown to output on HDMI and I can't find a way to have audio on both Stereo output and HDMI

Comment: Try "System setting"->"Sound" and choose "Simultaneous output"

Comment: Sorry I forgot to indicate that I'm with a Xubuntu workstation (with Openbox as default window manager) so this menu doesn't exist (Xfce or Openbox). I looked for all audio related menu/tools I can find but I only have pavucontrol, paprefs and alsamixer

Comment: Maybe your hardware doesn't support simultaneous output. This is quite often the case with laptops, where there is only one output device and you can choose between different profiles, e.g. headphones, speakers or  HDMI.